# How to set session in marklogic cluster?

Tags: load-balancing, session-management, marklogic-10

We've implemented a login page with application-level authentication, using the xdmp:login function to validate users and setting sessions using xdmp:get-session-field upon successful login. Our setup works seamlessly during testing on a single server with DNS. However, when testing on a MarkLogic cluster containing 7 nodes, we encounter an issue.

Upon clicking the login button, the system redirects to another server within the cluster where the session cannot be located, leading to a continuous redirection loop back to the login page. Interestingly, using hostnames instead of DNS resolves the problem.

We are using an ELB for the MarkLogic cluster. Could someone please provide suggestions or insights on how to address this issue?

Note: The MarkLogic cluster comprises 7 nodes, and the issue is observed when using DNS, but not when using hostnames.